# How to stop my program to be as daemon when running?

Tags: linux, java, nohup

I am running a Java script which is running as daemon. I am seeing the process running as daemon when I type `jps`. I don't want to run that program as  daemon, as I am thinking for it to be run automatically by a cron job. If I do so I will see many daemons will be running in the background, so I want to stop that. Can anyone please answer this as the Java program must run, but not as daemon.

I am using this command:

```
java -cp $CP com.sdp.cloudwatch.DevAWSCloudWatch
```

Before this I used:

```
nohup java -cp $CP com.sdp.cloudwatch.DevAWSCloudWatch &
```

To avoid the program being run as daemon I removed `nohup &` but even though I removed `nohup &` from the above command it is running as daemon.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect its not really running as daemon. A true daemon must fork, setsid and fork again (along with some other jiggery pokery) which can't be done from inside java.

Its more likely that you mean the process you invoke does not exit.

Your only practical option is to rewrite the java code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a script to launch your java process; in which case it is the script that you want to control (from running as duplicate instances).

You can create a temp file and lock it. Even though there is still open windows where things may slip, it usually works, because you would be scheduling your script once for every few minutes.

Look at : [Prevent duplicate cron jobs](https://serverfault.com/questions/82857/prevent-duplicate-cron-jobs-running).